# Can we control the order of locks in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

This is my scenario, I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
   [Id] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
   [Value] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [IndexColumnA] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [IndexColumnB] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_A] ON [MyTable] ([IndexColumnA])
CREATE INDEX [IX_B] ON [MyTable] ([IndexColumnB])
```

And have two use cases with two different update commands

```
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [Value] = '...' WHERE [IndexColumnA] = '...'
```

and

```
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [Value] = '...' WHERE [IndexColumnB] = '...'
```

Both update commands may update multiple rows and these commands caused a deadlock when executed concurrently.

My speculation is that the two update commands use different index when scanning the rows, the order placing locks on rows are therefore different. As the result, one update command may try place an U lock on a row which already has a X lock placed by another update command. (I am not a database expert, correct me if I was wrong)

One possible solution to this should be forcing database to place locks in the same order. According to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257217/why-am-i-getting-a-deadlock-for-a-single-update-query, it seems we can do this by `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... FOR UPDATE` in PostgreSQL.

Can we (and should we) do this in SQL Server? if not, is the only solution to this is handling the deadlock in application code?

Comment: @DaleK Thanks, I know we can place U locks with `with (updlock)`. However, I am not sure whether using it with `order by` forces database to place lock with desired order, and  whether using it is a good way to deal with deadlocks.

Comment: Your link is about a two-table and single row scenario while my case is about single table and multiple row, they are not exactly the same.

Comment: The reason is simply I didn't know we can accept an answer. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: I know all deadlocks are same in principle, but I am asking about handling deadlocks caused by two independent use case. I just can't lock the rows that are updated by another update command.

Comment: I totally understand UPDLOCK works perfectly with single row but my problem is about multiple rows!
As I understand, when two transactions trying to put locks on the same set of rows in different order, we can still get into trouble.

Comment: Sorry, missed that, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285180/can-update-lead-to-deadlocks-in-sql-server